# Improve update performance when setting column to null

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

Bit of a long shot here, but I have a simple query below:

```
begin transaction       

update s
set s.SomeField = null
from someTable s (NOLOCK)

rollback transaction
```

This runs in ~30 seconds sitting close to the SQL Server box.  Are there any tricks I can use to improve the speed. The table has 144,306 rows in it.

thanks.

Comment: Is `SomeField` part of an index? What happens if you do not rollback? Is rollback taking most of the time, or is it the nulling out?

Comment: Yes it is part of an index.  Rollback adds more time about 10 seconds.  Still 20 seconds seems too much.

Comment: `from someTable s (NOLOCK)` is utterly pointless. It won't reduce the amount of locking just use `update someTable  set SomeField = null`

Comment: If this is a regular manouevre, you are going to have to look at your schema or pay the price. Every index involved + the table and probably the indexes will clogg up as well..

Comment: @Tony - this is only done when no users are on the system.

Comment: @subt13 Another quick question: do you have any triggers that run when you update that table? You probably do not, but I figured I might ask anyway.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - no triggers.

Answer (score 2):

The single largest component of the performance of a large UPDATE command like this is going to be the speed of your DB log.

For best performance:

1. Make sure the DB log (LDF file) is on a separate physical spindle from the DB data (MDF file)
2. Avoid parity RAID for the log volume, such as RAID-5; RAID-1 or RAID-10 are better
3. Make sure that the DB log file is pre-grown, and that it's physically contiguous on disk
4. Make sure your server has enough RAM -- ideally, at least enough to hold all of the DB pages containing the modified rows

Using SSDs for your data drive may also help, because the command will create a large number of dirty buffers, which be flushed to disk later by the lazy writer; this can make other operations on the DB slow while it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no constraint on it, and you really need to set all values of that column to NULL, then I would test dropping the column and re-adding it.

Not sure if that would be faster or not, but I'd investigate it.

Comment: Not going to work.  This column is referenced by several indexes.  Not going to drop the indexes for this and recreate them.  That would take even longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [disabling the index temporarily](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/17/sql-server-disable-index-enable-index-alter-index/).

Comment: re-enabling means the indexes need to be rebuilt.

Comment: @MartinSmith That is absolutely correct. However, rebuilding an index all at once could prove to be cheaper than mixing updates to the index with updates to the table. I am not saying it would necessarily provide an improvement, but it has enough chance of succeeding to give it a try.

Comment: Disabling / rebuilding barely (couple seconds) improved the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the syntax of your query slightly, but I had no difference in my testing by doing that.  I was using `STATISTICS IO` and `STATISTICS TIME`.

You mention the column is indexed.  You could disable it / re-enable it as part of your transaction.  The t-sql for that is simple, see this - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/17/sql-server-disable-index-enable-index-alter-index/

I've had to do that in the past for similar jobs and it has worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement like this

```
Disable Index

Drop the column
Create the column

Rebuild index
```

I can guess that it will improve performance.

Comment: How is this different from the above answers besides the seemingly additional overhead of dropping/creating both the column and the indexes?